# Cypress not loading page headless after click login button

Tags: cypress, headless

when i run my script headless seems not load the next page, the video recorded after execute it, shows the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVF0g.jpg)

and fails after that with a timeout error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB1Mb.png)

here the test:
context('TS001-login', () => {

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('/');


})

const userName = "sdfgsdfg";
const passwrd = "gsdfgsdgg";

it.only('login with valid user and password', () => {
  
  cy.get('#j_username', {timeout : 31500}).type(userName);
  cy.get('#j_password', {timeout : 31500}).type(passwrd);
  //cy.contains('Login').click({force: true});
  cy.contains('Login').type('{enter}');      
  cy.get('#logout', {timeout : 71500}).should('be.visible');

  cy.wait(2500);

});



it.only('login with invalid user and valid password', () => {
  cy.get('#j_username', {timeout : 31500}).type('userName');
  cy.get('#j_password', {timeout : 31500}).type(passwrd);
  cy.contains('Login').click({force: true});
  cy.get('#error').should('contain', errorLP1);
  cy.wait(2500);

});
```

here the cypress.json:
{

```
"baseUrl": "http://salesportal-uat.xxxxx/",
"ignoreTestFiles": "**/ignore/*.spec.js",
"chromeWebSecurity": false,
"viewportWidth": 1280,
"viewportHeight": 720,
"defaultCommandTimeout": 30000,
"pageLoadTimeout": 60000,
"requestTimeout": 20000,
"retries": {
    "runMode": 1,
    "openMode": 1

},

"experimentalSessionAndOrigin": true
```

}

Also, this works perfect in protractor : headed and headless, but need it to work in cypress Im using version 9.6.1 and tried as well with 8.5.0 , Please help.

---

Tried with
before(() => {

cy.visit('/')

})
and works well in headed mode but not headless, Still having same results when tries to enter the page after click login, throwing timeout error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVF0g.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB1Mb.png)

Here working well in headed mode:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AioKG.png)

I think  cypress is doing something when executes it headless. Dunno what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a before() hook for cy.visit,

```
before(() => {

  cy.visit('/')

})
```

not in

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('/');


})
```

If you used to visit in beforeEach () hook, it will repeatedly try to access the basic URL you specified in your cypress.json during each test.

So,
`before()` runs once before all your code.
`beforeEach()` runs before each of your code blocks.

And also you can do the following to store all cookies between tests once.

```
beforeEach(function () {
  cy.getCookies().then(cookies => {
    const namesOfCookies = cookies.map(c => c.name)
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce(...namesOfCookies)
  })
})
```

Because after Each it blocks the execution of cypress clean cookies

And if your test failed again after this, due to being unable to find an element within mentioned time, then increase ```"pageLoadTimeout" in your cypress.json or use a custom timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is here you activated `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` in your cypress.json
since all session state is now cleared between tests.

You can use the `cy.session ()` command, which allows you to easily cache session information and reuse it through testing.

If you no need to access multiple domains within your test suite you disable or remove `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` in your cypress.json
Or if you need then you can improve this by using [cy.session()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session), please refer to the [document](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#SSO-login-custom-command)

Comment: If I take off experimentalSessionAndOrigin , when the script clicks login comes back to the login page, if I turn it on, after clicks login proceeds with the next page (all this in headed mode).

Comment: I did it with cy.session and got similar result,  here are the results : headed - OK: https://ibb.co/yfmypqT ; headless - NOT OK:  https://ibb.co/QYpK1LR

Comment: Im so done with this issue, Ill be keeping my test in protractor and work from there, a shame. #Cypress

Answer (score 0):

So could you please try, this in tour test spec file

```
beforeEach(function () {
  cy.getCookies().then(cookies => {
    const namesOfCookies = cookies.map(c => c.name)
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce(...namesOfCookies)
  })
})
```

And take off experimentalSessionAndOrigin in your cypress.json

Comment: Hi Pali, I took off the flag "experimentalSessionAndOrigin" from cypress json https://ibb.co/rkkX2Zn and added the cy.getCookies(...) in before each in the test https://ibb.co/2MSKqMp and fails in headed mode with chrome or edge browser, its like after click in login button comes back into the login page  , 
here the result https://ibb.co/x1bvw0d